# How many solar system bodies have had their magnetic fields directly measured?

Tags: rovers, lander, magnetic-field, flyby, measurement

Discussion below [this post](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55908/12102) lead me to wonder:

**Question:** How many solar system bodies have had their magnetic fields *directly* measured?

Inferences from radio or spectroscopic observations don't count for the purposes of this question, it's got to be some kind of *in situ* [magnetometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer), some magnetic field detector that has flown past or around or landed on a body, measured the magnetic field and reported the data back to Earth.

A measurement of zero, or of tiny fluctuations about zero certainly count as a measurement.