# What does a typical delta-v budget look like for a LEO satellite?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, delta-v, earth-observation

In terms of launch, initial orbit correction, stationkeeping, deorbiting, etc. for a typical 100-200 kg LEO satellite?

Is there any source online with specifications for non-private Earth-orbiting satellites?

Comment: not an answer but there is some related information at [Delta-V of Starlink Sattelites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36455/)