# How much krypton is stored on a Starlink satellite?

Tags: spacex, propulsion, communication-satellite, starlink, fuel-system

How much krypton (fuel) is there for the krypton-powered ion thrusters on Starlink satellites and how long does it last?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it is related: [Delta-V of Starlink Satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36471/12102)

Answer (score 1):

We don't know exactly how much krypton starlink satellites have, but some guesswork based on the orbital maneuvers performed says that they would need ~2.5 kg of fuel. See https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36471/40045 for more information.